# How can i pass the value to the field from excel sheet after clearing the field using clear method in selenium

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver

I have field called TIME with the default value 0.00. Now I need to pass some value like 8.00 from excel sheet, in order to perform this first i cleared the field which contains the default value 0.00 using clear method. But the issue is after clearing am not able to pass the value from excel.

How can I achieve this ? Can some one help me please ?

Thanks in advance..!

Regards
Sharath Bandi

Comment: So you need to read a value from excel and pass it to the element?

Comment: Yes Vignesh.. After clearing the default value am not  able to pass the value form excel but without doing clear its taking the value. The problem is its taking  0.008 if I pass 8.

Comment: please provide code snippets, to help you further